# Question about getblocktemplate

Tags: hash, getblocktemplate

I'm having trouble understanding getblocktemplate.

From https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate,

I see how to build the block header and then begin hashing by incrementing the nonce, the same as I would perform work on the result of a getwork call.

What I don't understand is the following

> Since you're making all the blocks yourself, you really don't ever need to get another template... until it's invalid.

After I construct my merkle root and then my block header, and hash away by incrementing the nonce, then what? How do I "create" a block? Surely I will overflow the nonce quickly with an ASIC - so what else am I varying while hashing?

I feel like I am missing a very important step.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look at BIP 22/23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a client has the template it can modify it to make the header different, giving you a new nonce range to search. In modern miners this happens thousands or tens of thousands of times a second.

- The timestamp in the header can be updated if needed, this is known in old software as `nRollTime`. This method is generally not used anymore because you only get one new range per second.
- The "extraNonce" can be updated, the random data in the coinbase transaction is altered and the merkle tree is re-hashed up to the root, which changes the header. This technique is used by Stratum miners as well.
- Transactions can be added or removed from the tree.

GBT and Stratum are distinct from an old system called `GetWork` which simply gave out just a partially hashed header, every time the nonce range was exhausted the client would need to make a new request to the server they were mining from. This is what your quote is alluding to.

Comment: Okay, so I should be updating the nonce and extra nonce, and possibly the timestamp if I don't feel like excluding any transactions then?

Comment: You must always update the timestamp or you will produce invalid blocks. Iterate the nonce until you reach `2^32`, then change the `extraNonce`.

Comment: The timestamp should always just be kept in sync with my current time?

Comment: That's correct.