# How is mining the exact same hash on every computer avoided?

Tags: mining-theory, hash, miner-configuration

How does the mining clients make sure that the seeds are not the exact same computed on every mining rig in the world with for example a GTX 1080 with the same speed? So that it is not the quickest miner that gets the reward.

For example. Seeds: 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD etc...

Is the seeds for computing hash just a counter up from 0? Or is the seeds for the hash totally random?

Comment: Effectively dupe https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113195/using-prng-to-get-better-mining-results

Answer (score 11):

Blocks commit to the set of transactions they contain, including the coinbase transaction. The coinbase transaction is the transaction which pays the subsidy/fees out to the miner who mined it.

Since every miner pays themselves in the blocks they're trying to construct, no two miners will ever attempt to build blocks that have identical coinbase transactions.

Comment: People often forget that the block "needs to know" who should receive the minted coin.

Comment: Is this the case for clients inside a mining pool as well?

Comment: @Taemyr, pool must give clients different seed, otherwise will be inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, in a pool the pool operator will assign different (sets of) coinbase transactions to different hashers. The pool must make sure that no two hashers ever work on the same problem, as that'd be duplicate work.